# Specifying user inputs by dynamic row from HTML form using Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, post

In HTML I have a form with 4 user inputs in a row inside a table. However, the number of rows that appear dynamically varies.

```
<form action="/edit" method="post">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   {% for row in profile_display['rows'] %} <!--# of rows that appear depend on this-->
    <tr>                             
     <td> <!--user input 1-->
      <form>
       <input id={{row[0]~'seq'}} name='seq' class="w-75" type="number" step=1 value="{{row[0]}}" ondblclick="editSeq(`{{row[0]~'seq'}}`);" readonly>             
      </form>
     </td>
     <td> <!--user input 2-->
      <form>
       <input id={{row[0]~'code'}} name='ing_code' class="w-75" value="{{row[1]}}" ondblclick="editCode(`{{row[0]~'code'}}`)" readonly>
      </form>
     </td>
     <td>{{row[2]}}</td>                
     <td> <!--user input 3-->
      <form>
       <input id={{row[0]~'weight'}} name='weight' class="w-75" type="number" step=.001 value="{{row[3]}}" ondblclick="editWeight(`{{row[0]~'weight'}}`);" readonly>
      </form>
     </td>
     <td> <!--user input 4-->
      <form>
       <input id={{row[0]~'ret'}} name='ret_code' class="w-75" value="{{row[4]}}" ondblclick="editRet(`{{row[0]~'ret'}}`)" readonly>
      </form>
     </td> 
   </tbody>
  </table>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

In Python, I am trying to create a function that updates a dataframe, profile_df, which contains preexisting data but can be updated based on user input in the HTML form.

```
@app.route('/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit():
global profile_df
if request.method == 'POST':
    profile_df=profile_df[profile_df['Food code']==food_display['Food Code']] 
    for index, row in profile_df.iterrows():
        row['Seq num']=request.form.get('seq') 
        row['Ingredient code']=request.form.get('ing_code')
        row['Ingredient weight (g)']=request.form.get('weight')
        row['Retention code']=request.form.get('ret_code')
return redirect('/')
```

While I can specify exactly which cells to update in the profile_df by using row['col'], I do not know how to specify exactly which cells to grab the user input from. I know I can grab user input using the 'name' attribute in the form, which I am doing, but since the number of rows in the form varies, just grabbing by 'name' wouldn't work. I am thinking of narrowing the request.form.get even further by somehow specifying the row, but am unsure how to do so. Below is my attempt which doesn't work but hopefully makes my intent clear. Basically, I am trying to further specify the exact row (# rows varies) in which a user input appears by both name and something else.

```
@app.route('/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit():
global profile_df
if request.method == 'POST':
    profile_df=profile_df[profile_df['Food code']==food_display['Food Code']] 
    for index, row in profile_df.iterrows():
        row['Seq num']=row[request.form.get('seq')]
        row['Ingredient code']=row[request.form.get('ing_code')]
        row['Ingredient weight (g)']=row[request.form.get('weight')]
        row['Retention code']=row[request.form.get('ret_code')]
return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this that way. 'name' tag in form needs to be unique in other case it just overrides.
I would do different 'name' for each row like you did with 'id' and then taking it that way:

```
for name, value in request.form.items():
    print(name, value)
```